# Trying to find connectivity in the Wikipedia Graph: Should I use the API or the relevant SQL Dump?

Tags: mysql, performance, graph-algorithm, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I apologize for the slightly obnoxious nature of my question.
A few years ago, I came across a [game](https://encyclopediadramatica.rs/Six_Degrees_of_Adolf_Hitler) that could be played on Wikipedia. The goal is to start from a random page and try to get to the 'Adolf Hitler' page by utilizing internal wikilinks within 5 clicks(6 degrees of separation). I found this to be an interesting take on the [Small-world experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_experiment) and tried it a few times, and was able to reach the target article within 5-6 clicks almost every time (however, there was no way for me to know if that was the shortest path or not).

As a project, I want to find out the degree of separation between a few(maybe hundreds, or thousands, if feasible) of random Wikipedia pages and Adolf Hitler's page in order to create a Histogram of sorts. My intention is to do an exhaustive search in a DFS manner from the root page (restricting the 'depth' of the search to 10, in order to ensure that the search terminates in case it has selected a bad path, or is running in cycles). So, the program would visit every article reachable within 10 clicks of the root article, and find the shortest way in which the target article is reachable.

**I realise that the algorithm described above would certainly take too long to run.** I have ideas for optimizations which I will play around with.

perhaps I will use a single source shortest path BFS based approach which seems to be more feasible considering that the degree of the graph would be quite high(mentioned later)

I will not mention all ideas for the algorithms here as they are not relevant to the question as in any possible implementation, I will have to query (directly by downloading relevant tables on my machine,  or through the API) the:

- [pagelinks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pagelinks_table) table which contains information about all internal links in all pages in the form of the 'id' of page containing the wikilink and the 'title' of the page that is being linked
- [page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table) table which contains relevant information for mapping the page 'title' to 'id'. This mapping is needed because of the way data is stored in the `pagelinks` table.

Before I knew Wikipedia's [schema](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout/diagram), naturally, I started exploring the [Wikipedia API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) and quickly found out that the following API query returns the list of all internal links on a given page, 500 at a time:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=links&titles=Mahatma%20Gandhi&pllimit=max`

Runnig this on MediaWiki's [API sandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=links&titles=Mahatma%20Gandhi&pllimit=max) a few times gives a request time of about 30ms for 500 link results returned. This is not ideal as even 100 queries of this nature would end up taking 3 seconds, which means I would certainly have to reduce the scope of my search somehow.

On the other hand, I could download the relevant SQL Dumps for the two tables [here](https://archive.org/download/enwiki-20170820) and use them with MySQL. English Wikipedia has aroud 5.5 million articles (which can be considered as vertices of graph). The **compressed** sizes of the tables are: around 5GB for the `pagelinks` table and 1GB for the `page` table. A single tuple of the `page` table is a lot bigger than that of the `pagelinks` table, however (max size of around 630 and 270 bytes, by my estimate). Sorry I could not provide the number of tuples in each table, as I haven't yet downloaded and imported the database.

Downloading the database seems appealing because: since I have the entire list of pages in the page table, I could resort to a single pair shortest path BFS approach from Adolf Hitler's page by tracking all the internal backlinks. This would end up finding the degree of seperation of every page in the database. I would also imagine that eliminating the bottleneck (internet connection) would speed up the process.

Also, I would not be overusing the API.

However, I'm not sure that my Desktop would be able to perform even at par with the API considering the size of the database.

What would be a better approach to pursue?

More generally, what kind of workload requires the use of an offline copy of the database rather than just the API?

While we are on the topic, in your experience, is such a problem even feasible without the use of supercomputing, or perhaps a server to run the SQL queries?

Comment: I would start by building an indexed table with two columns: from_url and to_url.  Then the algorithm can use that table.  After that it is an algorithm issue.

Comment: If you are curious about how other people did this have a look at [Getting to Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Getting_to_Philosophy).

Comment: There is no point in using the API; it takes too long and you will end up building a local database anyway (a kind of routing table) so better start with all the data in place.

Comment: You might want to look at wikibase, wikidata and transitive SPARQL queries. You'll need a database of internal page links instead of one with the WikiData knowledge graph.